# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. "problem"

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

I am trying to execute some examples about code generator for API.
I always have a problem when I arrive to make a command.
for example in this link https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/#install-grpc  when I executing the command that before the make command I get these results

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/****/*****/otapp/grpc/helloworld ex/grpc/cmak
e/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/******/***/otapp/grpc/helloworld ex/grpc/cmak
e/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"
```

after that when I am entering the make command I got the error message.
I tried with ubuntu and windows system and I still have the problem, I have "cmkae" package already installed on my pc

how I can solve this problem please?

Comment: Why would you bother with the make command. Cmake clearly encountered errors. You don't appear to have a compiler installed.

Comment: Did you run cmake from the Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat)?

Comment: dear sweenish i installed Cmake on my pc then added it to the path of variable environments, I execute the examples as is written in the tutorials

Comment: Dear JaMiT: no i opened the terminal (cmd,git,poweshell) i tried with three of them. i have VS 2019 it will work or I will need 2017? for that